# Primefaces showing list on a single row

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 2.2.1 and JSF 2.0 and I'm trying to show a list on a single row using p:dataTable. If I use the standard p:column, every list member it is shown on different rows. 
So if I have an ArrayList, how to show it on a single row, multiple columns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you want to display your list members? Separated by a comma, for example?

In that case you could use something like this:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.fakeList}">
    <p:column>
        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.myList}">
             <h:outputText value="#{item.property}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Notice that the #{bean.fakeList} must return a list of 1 element, so that the dataTable will have an item to iterate, otherwise it'll show you the 'No records' message.

The output of this code will come in a single row and will be something like: value1, value2, value3, ...

I'm not sure if that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<p:dataTable>`, just use [`<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf) or [`<p:dataList>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListHome.jsf) (with a bit of CSS to float the items left).